# Scrollspy not working Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wanna use scrollspy feature in my code but it doesn't work

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#featured"><h1></h1></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#featured">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#mission">Mission</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
```

and the body tag

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".fixed-top">
```

Where might be the problem?

Comment: The markup looks good so make sure you have [jquery, popper, etc.. installed correctly](http://getbootstrap.com) and there are no JS errors in the browser console (F12).

Comment: refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy&stacked=h

Comment: Everything installed correctly but it doesn't work

Comment: It does work: https://www.codeply.com/go/NKigSX3pzW .. post all of the code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/go/3vy1mLRyCa
Thanks in advance

Comment: I forgot to put my css. check it now

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      position: relative; 
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".fixed-top" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#featured"><h1></h1></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#featured">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#mission">Mission</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>

<div id="featured" class="container-fluid bg-success" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 1</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="mission" class="container-fluid bg-info" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 2</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>
<div id="services" class="container-fluid bg-secondary" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
  <h1>Section 3</h1>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually the problem is. it adds active class to the nav-link class instead of nav-item. so is there any way to fix that?